# Proper escape sequence for a non-standard file name

Tags: command-line, filenames, rm

I'm trying to remove a file I made by mistake using `--exclude` with `tar`. I ended up making a `tar` file named `--exclude=*.tar` Now I want to delete it but I'd like to rename it first. How do I escape it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two straightforward ways to do this using just `rm`:

```
rm -- --exclude=*.tar
```

or

```
rm ./--exclude=*.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used `mv ./--exclude=*.tar deleteThisFile` and that worked fine.

Comment: I think the only things you ever need to escape are spaces (if you don't quote) or quotes (if you do quote).